# Can Azure Logic Apps Standard be hosted in an App Service Plan like Azure Function?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

**Background:**

I don't have an App Service Environment and I don't want to pay for that.

I have an App Service Plan that I have a few App Service and Functions running in it.

I am trying to clarify if Logic Apps can be hosted on an existing App Service plan along with my other App Services and Functions.

I am going through this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing

and I read:

> If you choose this option, you're charged for the instances used by
> the App Service plan and for running your logic app workflows. No
> other charges apply.

The statement could be misleading, I just wanted to confirm it with this question.

**Question**

Can Azure Logic Apps Standard be hosted in an App Service Plan like Azure Functions?

Comment: there is only one plan for logic app standard: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/logic-apps/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way you can add the existing Azure Service plan except if the App service plan is inside some Azure Service Environment.

> When you create or deploy logic apps with the Logic App (Standard) resource type, you can use the Workflow Standard hosting plan in all Azure regions. You also have the option to select an existing App Service Environment v3 resource as your deployment location, but you can only use the App Service plan with this option.

However, it is advisable to only have one WS App Service Plan for Logic Apps Standard as there may be instances where the requests for CPU or memory are more or less.

> Having multiple Logic Apps Standard associated to a single WS App Service Plan can help you manage better your cost, but when one of the apps starts to request more CPU or memory from the host than the others, you can have issues where that app is driving the scale of the underlying App Service plan, affecting the performance of the other apps associated to the App Service Plan.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Standard (single-tenant) - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing#standard-single-tenant)
2. [Organizing logic apps workflows with Logic Apps Standard - Wagner Silveira](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/organizing-logic-apps-workflows-with-logic-apps-standard/ba-p/3251179#:%7E:text=All%20apps%20are%20being%20hosted%20by%20the%20same,any%20impact%20on%20Shipment%20Notification%20or%20Overnight%20Batches.)